# Advanced Query in Invokable Apex

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

I am needing to run an advanced query in a Record Triggered Lightning Flow that references parent objects. The query runs, but I cannot figure out how to get it to run in an invokable method. I am passing the asset Id to the Apex and then wanting to return the list that my query returns.

I am trying to run the query from an invokable method inside a lightning flow. I am passing the record to the flow. In the debug logs it shows the query and then immediately after it shows the error below.

I receive the following error:

Error Occurred: An Apex error occurred: System.UnexpectedException: Bad rightOperand type: got SObjectScriptRow: operator e dataType 1

```
public with sharing class queryAssets{
@InvocableMethod(label='Get assets' description='Runs a complex query and returns a list of assets.')
    public static List<Asset> GetAssets (List<Asset> curAssets) {
       for(Asset assetObj :  List<Asset> assetsList = [Select Id, Name, AccountId, 
                              FROM Asset
                              Where Id IN: curAssets
                              AccountId != NULL 
                              AND (Product2.Cost__c != null OR Product2.Dealer_Cost__c!= null 
                              OR Product2.Dealer_Labor_Charge__c != null)
                                                       AND Quantity != null]) {
                                                           
            return assetsList;                                                   
                          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck, exactly?

Comment: I get the following error:

Error Occurred: An Apex error occurred: System.UnexpectedException: Bad rightOperand type: got SObjectScriptRow: operator e dataType 1

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications. You should always include any error messages verbatim. We are not mind readers.

Comment: Also showing us how you are trying to call this code would likely help. The more we have to fill in the gaps, the less likely you will receive a timely and useful answer to your question.

Comment: It looks like you might have an issue with the data your SOQL bind variable is trying to access. Can you try Mapping your `List<Asset> curAssets` to `new Map<Id, Asset>(curAssets).keySet()` and then access the Map `keySet` in your bind variable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understand exactly what the error message means, but I suspect it is referring to the 'rightOperand' in your for loop, where you are declaring a List variable.  See [For Loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for.htm) in the Apex Dev Guide for the correct syntax.
Additionally, your query is not valid (extra comma, missing `AND`), and you are trying to return inside the loop.  Assuming your input and output types are correct, I think you want this:

```
public with sharing class queryAssets{
    @InvocableMethod(label='Get assets' description='Runs a complex query and returns a list of assets.')
    public static List<Asset> GetAssets(List<Asset> curAssets) {
        // retrieve results
        List<Asset> assetsList = [
            SELECT Id, Name, AccountId 
              FROM Asset
             WHERE Id IN :curAssets
               AND AccountId != NULL 
               AND (Product2.Cost__c != null 
                    OR Product2.Dealer_Cost__c!= null 
                    OR Product2.Dealer_Labor_Charge__c != null)
               AND Quantity != null
        ];  
        // if you need to further modify/filter results, you could do so here.

        // return results
        return assetsList;                                                   
    }
}
```